# how can I make a product between matrices on cplex

Tags: cplex

I have a boolean value: m[c][r][t] which is equal to 1  if specialty c is assigned to room r on day t; 0 otherwise.
To describe the data I created 2 matrices: v[c][r],j[r][t],and I made the product between these to get m: m[c][r][t]==v[c][r]*[r][t];
The problem is that it all returns me values equal to 0, how can I do it?
The code is this:

```
int nspeciality=...;  
int nroom=...;  
int ndays=...;  

range speciality=0..nspeciality;  
range room=1..nroom;  
range days=0..ndays;  

int m[speciality][room][days];  
int v[speciality][room]=...;  
int j[room][days]=...;  

-----
subject to{      

forall(c in speciality, r in room, t in days)      
  m[c][r][t]==v[c][r]*[r][t];      
-------      
in .dat      

nspeciality=3;      
nroom=4;      
ndays=6;     

v=[[1,1,0,0],      
   [1,0,0,1],      
   [1,1,0,0],  
   [0,0,1,0]];        
j=[[0,1,1,0,0,1,0],      
   [1,0,0,1,1,0,0],      
   [1,1,1,0,1,1,1],      
   [1,0,0,0,0,0,1]];
```

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want is this:

```
int v[speciality][room]=...;  
int j[room][days]=...;  
int m[c in speciality][r in room][t in days] = v[c][r] * j[r][t];
```

This defines `m` depending on `v` and `j`.

What you currently have in your model is an array `m` of data that is not initialized. Since it is not initialized, all elements in this array are set to 0. Then you add a *constraint* that each slot in `m` must be equal to the product of the respective values in `v` and `j`. Since none of the three are variables, this constraints is either trivially true or trivially false.